# why $http cannot get data sometime when used in controller function?

Tags: angularjs, http, controller

In my angularjs application, I use $http to get data in controller.

```
app.controller("testController", function($scope, $http, $log){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/get-data/',
        params: {'data-id': 1}
    })
    .then(function(response){
        $log.debug("success");
     },function(){
        $log.debug("failed");
     }
    );
}
```

But it's so weried that the code does not work sometime, the $http method seems do nothings. It happens a few times but I cannot find the reason.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: url: '/get-data/', url value is wrong check it.

Comment: type the url in the browser and check if it is working

Comment: `does not work` means nothing, provide details

Comment: the url is relative location. "does not work" means it seems not running, just like no such method was called.

Comment: I'm sure the Url is correct, because in most situations, it works well and a message 'success' output in the broswer console.

Comment: Maybe you can add a logging statement before `$http(...)`, so that when "does not work" situation happens, it can be confirmed whether the whole controller code is ignored, or `$http(...)` code is broken.